# How to erase/comment the middlename and lastname in default-address.html file in the module-costumer

Tags: magento2, php, adminhtml, html

Good day people, I have been trying to erase or comment middlename and lastname in default-address.html, this is the original file, you can find it in : vendor/magento/module-customer/view/adminhtml/web/template/default-address.html

```
<div data-bind="attr: {class: contentClass}">
<div
    data-bind="attr: {class: 'fieldset-wrapper address-information ' + defaultAddressClass}"
>
    <address>
        <div
            class="address_caption"
            data-bind="attr: {id: defaultAddressId}"
        >
            <text args="title"></text>
            <each args="data: elems, as: 'element'">
                <render if="hasTemplate()"></render>
            </each>
        </div>
        <div class="address_details" ifnot="_.isEmpty($data.address)">
            <text args="address.prefix" if="address.prefix"></text>
            <text args="address.firstname"></text>
            <text args="address.middlename" if="address.middlename"></text>
            <text args="address.lastname"></text>
            <text args="address.suffix" if="address.suffix"></text>
            <br />
            <if args="address.company">
                <text args="address.company"></text>
                <br />
            </if>
            <if args="address.street">
                <text
                    args="address.street"
                    if="_.isString(address.street)"
                ></text>
                <text
                    args="_.filter(_.values(address.street), function (value) { return _.isString(value)}).join(', ')"
                    ifnot="_.isString(address.street)"
                ></text>
                <br />
            </if>
            <text args="address.city + ', '" if="address.city"></text>
            <text args="address.region + ', '" if="address.region"></text>
            <if args="address.postcode">
                <text args="address.postcode"></text>
                <br />
            </if>
            <text args="address.country"></text>
            <if args="address.telephone">
                <br />T:
                <a
                    attr="href: 'tel:' + address.telephone"
                    text="address.telephone"
                ></a>
            </if>
            <if args="address.fax">
                <br />F: <text args="address.fax"></text>
            </if>
            <if args="address.vat_id">
                <br />VAT: <text args="address.vat_id"></text>
            </if>
        </div>
        <translate
            args="notExistsMessage"
            if="_.isEmpty($data.address)"
        ></translate>
    </address>
</div>
```

And this is the one I created in my own module, the path is this one: app/code/MyCompany/AdminUserForms/view/adminhtml/web/template/default-address.html

Is basically the same file but with the middlename and lastname commented, If I comment the same line in the original magento file it worked, but when I try to do it in my own module doesn't work:

```
<div data-bind="attr: {class: contentClass}">
<div
    data-bind="attr: {class: 'fieldset-wrapper address-information ' + defaultAddressClass}"
>
    <address>
        <div
            class="address_caption"
            data-bind="attr: {id: defaultAddressId}"
        >
            <text args="title"></text>
            <each args="data: elems, as: 'element'">
                <render if="hasTemplate()"></render>
            </each>
        </div>
        <div class="address_details" ifnot="_.isEmpty($data.address)">
            <text args="address.prefix" if="address.prefix"></text>
            <text args="address.firstname"></text>
            <!-- <text args="address.middlename" if="address.middlename"></text>
            <text args="address.lastname"></text> -->
            <text args="address.suffix" if="address.suffix"></text>
            <br />
            <if args="address.company">
                <text args="address.company"></text>
                <br />
            </if>
            <if args="address.street">
                <text
                    args="address.street"
                    if="_.isString(address.street)"
                ></text>
                <text
                    args="_.filter(_.values(address.street), function (value) { return _.isString(value)}).join(', ')"
                    ifnot="_.isString(address.street)"
                ></text>
                <br />
            </if>
            <text args="address.city + ', '" if="address.city"></text>
            <text args="address.region + ', '" if="address.region"></text>
            <if args="address.postcode">
                <text args="address.postcode"></text>
                <br />
            </if>
            <text args="address.country"></text>
            <if args="address.telephone">
                <br />T:
                <a
                    attr="href: 'tel:' + address.telephone"
                    text="address.telephone"
                ></a>
            </if>
            <if args="address.fax">
                <br />F: <text args="address.fax"></text>
            </if>
            <if args="address.vat_id">
                <br />VAT: <text args="address.vat_id"></text>
            </if>
        </div>
        <translate
            args="notExistsMessage"
            if="_.isEmpty($data.address)"
        ></translate>
    </address>
</div>
```

Can someone help me out with this?

Comment: Check this link :
https://www.thecoachsmb.com/how-to-override-html-file-in-magento-2/?utm_source=rss&utm_medium=rss&utm_campaign=how-to-override-html-file-in-magento-2

Comment: @Jasvir Singh, thanks for the help, it worked!

Comment: Glad to hear that. cheers !